# AngularJS UI Router URL parameter vanishes when changing states

Tags: angularjs, nested, angular-ui-router

I am attempting to change the state of my AngularJS application via a button click using UI Router. When I press the button, the desired information is sending correctly, however, when the state changes, the URL parameter is vanishing. For example, if my route is defined as /parent/state/child/:param and I go to /parent/state/child/3, when the transition finishes, the "3" disappears, and I'm left at /parent/state/child/.

I've tried transitioning using

```
$state.go('parentState.childState', {param: 3});
```

as well as

```
$location.path('/parent/state/child/3);
```

even

```
$window.location.href = '/parent/state/child/3;
```

All have had the same result.

This is my state file:

```
(function() {
    'use strict'
    angular.module('app')
        .config(states);
    states.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider'];
    function states($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        $stateProvider.state({
            name: 'parentState',
            url: '/parent/state',
            abstract: true,
            template: '<ui-view/>'
        })
        .state({
            name: 'parentState.childState',
            url: '/child/:param',
            templateUrl: 'some/route',
            controller: function ($stateParams) {
                console.log($stateParams);
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

The child state's template URL is being loaded correctly. I am also able to see that the value being set in my `$state.go('parentState.childState, {param: value});` is correct, however, when I output `$stateParams` to the console I get `{param: ""}`. Even when I try to go directly to a link (i.e., type /parent/state/child/5 into my browser) the final parameter vanishes.

Any thoughts as to what I might be doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

Due to how my application is setup, I'm unable to use `resolve` with UI router. Instead, I have a function set up to prevent the default state change, run the things that need to be resolved, and if they finish successfully, continue with the original transition. In that section, I was using `$state.go(toState.name);` when I should have been using `$state.go(toState.name, toParams);`. Since the parameters were not being passed on, they were being lost in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to set the params explicitly in the state:

```
.state({
  name: 'parentState.childState',
  url: '/child',
  params: {
    mySpecialParam: null
  },
  templateUrl: 'some/route',
  controller: function ($stateParams) {
    console.log($stateParams);
  }
})
```

$stateParams should now display { mySpecialParam: null }

When you go from one state to another:

```
$state.go('parentState.childState', { mySpecialParam: 3 })
```

Or

```
<a ui-sref="parentState.childState({ mySpecialParam: 3 })">View childState</a>
```

Also, I'd advise making your parameter names less like 'param/params', and something semantic to the value, so it's obvious.

For more information on this specific part of stateProvider, see the [URL Routing](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing) page for ui-router.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already tried that, and it has the exact same result. And the parameter names that I used here was only a placeholder.